# Django: filter foreign keys

Tags: python, django, model, filter, django-queryset

I have the following code:

```
        query = Entry.objects.all()
        print 'authors ' + repr([x.id for x in authors])
        print 'query ' + repr(query)
        print 'query ids ' + repr([x.author.id for x in query])
        query.filter(author__in=authors)
        print 'filtered ids ' + repr([x.author.id for x in query])
```

Which outputs this:

```
        authors [2]
        query [<Entry: test>, <Entry: test>]
        query ids [2, 3]
        filtered ids [2, 3]
```

Obviously, 3 is not in [2]. So, why filtered ids are [2, 3] and not just [2]?

Regards

Comment: Nevermind. Assigning result of .filter() is clearly better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `query.filter(author__in=authors)`, it returns a new queryset. It does not modify the existing queryset.

If you assign the new queryset to query, then you will get the result you were expecting.

```
query = query.filter(author__in=authors)
print 'filtered ids ' + repr([x.author.id for x in query])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of your current filter:

```
query = query.filter(author__in=authors)
```